# Do transfer edges add to the distance cost of a route?

Tags: network-analyst, gis-principle

Transfer edges are commonly used in a network dataset to carry a time cost in one direction only (either to-from or from-to). This is fine if the impedance used is time, i.e. find the route that will take the shortest time. However, if the impedance is now set to distance (find the shortest route), will the length of the transfer edges unfairly impact the length of the route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you mean "unfairly"? The solve will take into account a distance field that you set as an evaluator. You could use Shape_Length for the actual length of the edge, or you could create your own field that has some other distance attribute and set the evaluator to that.

Comment: I'm not actually sure what I meant when I asked this question, I was feeling quite overwhelmed by NA at the time. I think I was worried that if the stop was offset from the route, and a transfer edge of say 2m connected them, would that lengthen the route by 2m? I don't think that makes sense,  but you have answered the question in terms of how the solve works, so I will accept :)

Comment: Haha, thank you. And I do not think that if the stop was offset 2m from the edge it would add an additional 2m to the route distance. This is because of what I said above, that the length is calculated based on the actual network (or attributes assigned to it), and that you have the option of stops being located even when placed not directly on the network. Because you set the search/snapping tolerance yourself, you are assigning the degree of (true) travel that is being omitted from the directions.